# how to use calc(fit-content + 10vh)

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to add 10vh on top of the size of my div. fit-content doesn't work as far as i know with calc so does someone have anything i can replace it with or is there anyway it can work with calc.

In my css

```
.container {
 height: calc(fit-content + 10vh)
}

. container div {
 width: 90vw
 height: auto
}
```

In my react app

```
<div class="container">
 <div></div>
</div>
```

the height of the div needs to be auto because of the content inside of the div. But that is way i cant just say the height of the div + 10vh by my self.

Comment: have you considered using padding?

Comment: yes that doesnt fix the problem sadly it just crops the inner div

Comment: How does adding `padding-top: 10vh;` crop the inner div? Can you pop some code up? That's the standard way of doing it.

Comment: I bet you have a `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` somewhere in your CSS we haven't seen, as the padding, by default, is not included in the height or auto height of the box and would therefor be a good solution.

Comment: padding indeed worked with proper box-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that would help. By the way, `height` is `auto` by default.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}

.container div {
  width: 90vw;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>Hello there,</div>
  <div>Luuk van Dijk</div>
</div>
```